# Instafeed - Instagram: this user does not exist

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am using http://instafeedjs.com/ on my development site, I've got it to pull the most recent 20 photos with a username so I know my code is fine.

I have tried to register a different user to pull their details and I get the following error:-

Instagram: this user does not exist

I believe the User ID is correct, I got it from here http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id#

User ID: 1992159860

I have done the following:-

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token&scope=public_content

And agreed to the popup asking me to authorize but I still get the user id is incorrect, when I put my other user id, it works so I don't understand what's wrong here?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay I realised what the problem was, for anyone who may get the same issue just go to:-

https://www.instagram.com/developer

Edit your client and click on the 'Sandbox' tab, and invite the username for the profile you are pulling information from under 'Sandbox Users'.

I basically was logged in to my developer account when I registered the application so I needed to invite the user it was pulling the information from.